# how to overflow-x with starting position on the right hand side?

Tags: css, position, overflow

I have a `div` within a `div`. The parent's width is 600px with `overflow-x: scroll;` and the childs' width is 1200px .

On page load the left hand side of the child `div` is shown with the ability to scroll towards the right hand side.

I am not sure how to get the starting position to be the right hand side instead of the left. Any tips are much appreciated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple fix is to make your container read right to left (by default the scroll will then sit on the right).

Add the line `direction: rtl` to the parent divs CSS and then `direction: ltr` to the child div (so text in the child will read left to right).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kXUc/